# Yii Bootstrap Extension IE8 active navigation bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, yii, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the (most popular) Bootstrap extension in Yii made by Chris83, and when I make a bootTab menu, in IE8 the active class that is applied to one of the tabs doesn't go away when another tab is clicked sometimes.

So I end up with 2 active tabs at once. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in the BootTabbable (previously called BootTabs) widget. It has been fixed in the current BETA release (0.9.11), so you can either apply the changes manually or upgrade to the BETA version. If you're not in a hurry you could also wait for the next release, which should be live early next week.